# How to present a view controller programmatically

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a button inside my nib file. How can I programmatically present another view controller when the user taps on this button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to create an action for your button, normally via `Ctrl`+`drag`. On that action implementation you should alloc the destination ViewController. The code would be something like this:

```
- (IBAction)buttonTapped {
    MyViewController *modalViewController = [MyViewController new];
    [self presentViewController:modalViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Since you said that your file is a nib, I'm assuming that you aren't on a storyboard with both ViewControllers on it and the ViewController to be presented is code based. If this isn't the case, please elaborate your question.

**As requested: Loading a VC from a storyboard**

```
- (IBAction)buttonTapped {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MyStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    RSSViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RSSVC"];
    // OR If is initial
    // RSSViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];

    viewController.feedURL = @"...";
    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

If you need, ViewController identifier should be set in the Identity Inspector in the Storyboard.

[image: Storyboard Identity Inspector]

Comment: Yes for some reason the xib view controller isn't in the same storyboard. How can I connect the button to present a certain view controller ?

Comment: Also, can this button pass data the next view controller say a list urls that need to be loaded in a RSS feed?

Comment: @jmwhite132 I've improved my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

As I understood , you want to push new viewController on Button click . Please try this

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked {
    MyViewController *myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc]init];
    [self presentViewController: myViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer the below screenshots

First : control+drag the button[image]

Second: Once you release the mouse,it shows you the box[image]

Third:Click Connection Dropdown box.It shows you 3 option[image]

Fourth:Choose or Select Action from the drop down.

Five : Finally give action name [image]

now in ViewContoller.h the action method is

```
 - (IBAction)actionGoNextPage:(id)sender;
```

Then in ViewContoller.m

```
 #import "SecondViewController.h"

 - (IBAction)actionGoNextPage:(id)sender
 {
    SecondViewController *secondVC = [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
   [self presentViewController:secondVC animated:YES completion:nil];
 }
```